# Meteorjs - Android App package not signed correctly error

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, google-play, sign

I've recently  **published** my app to google play by using instructions on this [link](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store).

I could download it from the google play store on my phone but I couldn't do it with any other phones. Instead I got a message saying : "package file was not signed correctly"

Now I signed and uploaded the app, I can't sign it with another key and upload it anyway. So, what should I do? And what is the correct way to sign a meteor app for android google play?

Best,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently I'm answering my own questions but if somebody faces with this problem, I would like to help.

So here is what I followed:

```
meteor deploy your-desired-app-hostname.meteor.com
meteor build ~/build-output-directory --server=your-desired-app-hostname.meteor.com
keytool -genkey -alias your-app-name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
cd ~/build-output-directory/android/
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 unaligned.apk your-app-name
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs unaligned.apk
~/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/build-tools/20.0.0/zipalign 4 unaligned.apk production.apk
```

And uploaded production.apk as a new version. I hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: did you have a problem republishing the app with another signature?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, there is -unfortunately- not such thing as publishing your app with another signature. Although I've answered this with the full publish process, I jumped over the key creating step and used the same alias. Signing step and verifying step were the things worked for me.

Comment: I ended up taking down the application and publishing a new one with the same name. Newbie mistake. Thanks, your answer helped me though.